# How to get events from an e-commerce website and display the event data on a webpage

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, events, spring-kafka

I have recently started learning spring, and spring-Kafka. Currently I am working on a project so that I can get event data from an e-commerce website (can be a clone of an e-commerce website). I want to display the event data by creating an endpoint for the same. Till now , I have created a spring application that provides login, signup and view functionality. I have created an User entity, a DAO, a user custom service and a controller to create endpoints and connected with jdbc connector. The frontend of the project is done through creating thymeleaf templates. I wanted to get the event data from an e-commerce website and display only filtered insights from the data on my application by creating another endpoint and I want to save the filtered data on Mysql database. Can anyone please explain to me what all things I need to learn, and what would be the flow for creating such functionality?

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know the flow as I am a newbie to backend technologies